# How to show a sequence of independent random variables do not almost surely converge by definition?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a sequence of independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ where

$$ X_n =
  \begin{cases}
    1      & \quad \text{with probability} \  1/n  \\
    0    & \quad \text{with probability} \ 1-1/n
  \end{cases}
$$

In my book, it claims that while $X_n \to 0$ in probability, it is not true almost surely. The book gives a very short outline of the proof, but I am not sure if it is correct. It writes that: for $0 < \epsilon <1$, $P\left(\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty \{|X_m - X| > \delta\}\right) = 1- \lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_m = 0 \ \forall m \text{ s.t. } n \leq m)$. I am not sure why this line can show that almost sure convergence to $0$ is not possible.

The definition of almost sure converge I take is to be: $\forall \epsilon, \delta >0, \exists n_0=n_0(\epsilon, \delta) \text{ s.t. } P(\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty \{|X_m -X|> \delta\})\leq \epsilon$. Can someone tell me what the author's line intends to show? Thank you

Comment: You left out the absolutely crucial information that the random variables are *independent*.

Comment: I changed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That a sequence of members of $\{0,1\}$ approaches $0$ means that after some finite number of terms it is always $0$.

For $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ to converge almost surely to $0$, it would have to be the case that
$$
P( \text{for some finite number } N, \text{ for all } n\ge N,\  X_n=0) = 1.
$$

The [second Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) tells us that that happens only if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n<\infty$, but we know that that is false.

Comment: Hi, did you mean to have the probability statement equal to 1? Thanks!

Comment: @user136503 : Yes.  Fixed. $\qquad$

Comment: Hi sorry just one more thing, in the Borel-Cantelli lemma, they phrase that if the sum of the probabilities are finite, then the probability of the limsup is 0. Here, you have that is it 1, are you using a converse definition? thanks!

Comment: The  _second_ Borel–Cantelli lemma says if the sum of all the probabilities _is_ (note I say "is", not "are", since "sum" is singular) infinite and the events are independent, then infinitely many of the events happen.  That a partial converse of the first Borel–Cantelli lemma.  It's only partial since it has the additional assumption of independence.  What I used here is the contrapositive of the _second_ Borel–Cantelli lemma. $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question but I thought that the contrapositive is to say, "If the events do not happen infinitely often, then the sum of the probabilities isnt infinite and the events arent independent." It seems that here we are just failing to satisfy one of the conditions of the second borel-cantelli lemma and hence cant use it. Is that equivalent to the contrapositive?

Comment: If the events are independent, then $(A\Longrightarrow B)$. The contraposition was done _within_ the part that is in round brackets above, so this "contrapositive" is "If the events are independent, the $((\text{not } B) \Longrightarrow (\text{not }A))$.  However, if one were to write "If $\{$the events are independent and the sum is infinite$\}$ then infinitely many of them happen", then contraposition yields this: "If it is not the case that infinitely many of them happen then $\{$EITHER the sum is not infinite OR they are not independent$\}$." The negation of $[P\text{ and }Q]$ is $\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$ $[\text{either (not }P)\text{ or (not }Q)]$. (And this is an _inclusive_ "or".) $\qquad$

Comment: awesome, get it now, thank you!!!